# How to extract all WhatsApp data before Feb 8 2020 when privacy terms change against your favour?

Tags: ios, backup, whatsapp.app

All chats
All links
All photos
All videos
for all contacts

Dump them out somehow in a way in which I can easily access them for future reference

Comment: I haven't tried it, but this paid app - [Dr.Fone - WhatsApp Transfer](https://drfone.wondershare.com/whatsapp-transfer-backup-and-restore.html) claims it can copy everything from WhatsApp to your computer. Another app claims [it can extract data from Whatapp Backups](https://www.tenorshare.com/whatsapp-tips/top-3-whatsapp-backup-extractor-2018.html).

Comment: Backing it up locally will not affect WhatsApp's ability to still share that data with Facebook… unless you live in the EU where it's simply illegal for them to do that, so no changes will be made to your account, even if you had to 'agree' to the new terms or close the account.

Comment: I'd recommend using [iMazing](https://imazing.com/) for managing, exporting, and viewing, your iOS device's files. One particularly nice feature that iMazing supports is the ability to export WhatsApp conversations in PDF form as well as all media items. The free version of iMazing is limited to a certain number of exports, though.

Comment: @CuriosityCalls That sounds like an answer especially if you can show the details of how to do this

Comment: The 'terms' aren't really changing: they've been harvesting the non-encrypted metadata for years. https://www.wired.com/story/whatsapp-facebook-data-share-notification

Answer (score 2):

I originally wrote this as a comment, but since one user suggested I write it as an answer, here it is:

I'd recommend using [iMazing](https://imazing.com/) for managing, exporting, and viewing, your iOS device's files. One particularly nice feature that iMazing supports is the ability to export WhatsApp conversations in PDF form as well as all media items. **NOTE:** the free version of iMazing is limited to a certain number of exports, though.

iMazing's website has pretty detailed guides and explanations on how to manage your WhatsApp data. Go to their "[Export WhatsApp Chats](https://imazing.com/print-and-export-iphone-whatsapp-chats)" page (feel free to read it to see what you can do with iMazing) and scroll down to the **How To's** section. Here, you'll see the following support pages:

1. **How to export and Print WhatsApp Chats and Attachments from iPhone?** ([link](https://imazing.com/guides/export-and-print-whatsapp-chats-from-iphone-to-mac-pc))
2. **How to transfer WhatsApp from one iPhone to another?** ([link](https://imazing.com/guides/how-to-transfer-whatsapp-from-one-iphone-to-another))

They include YouTube videos as well in their support page articles to show you how to export the data. All the GUI interface pictures are for their macOS version, however the procedure is virtually identical on Windows.

---

On a side note, iMazing also provides a very powerful feature: exploring your iPhone's *file system* (support article [here](https://imazing.com/guides/file-system-view-in-imazing)). It's a super cool feature that allows you to explore how iPhones store their data and all.